# Ubuntu phone does not autolock

Tags: ubuntu-touch

My MX4 ubuntu version is not autolocking anymore. It does wake up for notifications, and leaves the screen on. This is a major battery drain. This has either been since I updated to ubuntu-touch/stable/meizu.en r2, or since I set screen lock time to never and back to 1 minute. (I noticed the behaviour only when I set the lock time back to 1 minute, and I had updated by then)

Now the questions are: Which process monitors this? Why is it staying awake? Which file holds the actual timeout settings? How can I investigate what's going on?

**EDIT**

So I've also filed a bug on launchpad for this, but so far noone else seems to be affected. Is it really just me? I've added some information for powerd, but I'm not sure that's the service that manages this.

When I ran `powerd-cli test`all passed except the first:

```
Test: checkForDbusName(test_dbusname, 0, requests, TRUE)
    result: FAILED
Test: checkForDbusName(powerd_cli_bus_name, 1, requests, TRUE)
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(main_cookie) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: checkForDbusName(powerd_cli_bus_name, 0, requests, TRUE)
    result: PASSED
Test: requestSysState(name, POWERD_SYS_STATE_ACTIVE, &cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: requestSysState(name, POWERD_SYS_STATE_ACTIVE, &cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: requestSysState(name, POWERD_SYS_STATE_ACTIVE, &cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: requestSysState(name, POWERD_SYS_STATE_ACTIVE, &cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: requestSysState(name, POWERD_SYS_STATE_ACTIVE, &cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: requests->len >= TEST_NUM_SYS_REQUESTS+1
    result: PASSED
Test: checkForDbusName(powerd_cli_bus_name, TEST_NUM_SYS_REQUESTS+1, requests, TRUE)
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: requests->len >= 1
    result: PASSED
Test: checkForDbusName(powerd_cli_bus_name, 1, requests, TRUE)
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(cookies[i]) == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState("bad cookie") == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: requests->len >= 1
    result: PASSED
Test: checkForDbusName(powerd_cli_bus_name, 1, requests, TRUE)
    result: PASSED
Test: requestSysState("test-cookie", POWERD_SYS_STATE_SUSPEND, &cookie) == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: requestSysState("test-cookie", -1, &cookie) == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: requestSysState("test-cookie", POWERD_NUM_POWER_STATES, &cookie) == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: requestSysState("test-cookie", POWERD_NUM_POWER_STATES+1, &cookie) == FALSE
    result: PASSED
Test: clearSysState(main_cookie) == TRUE
    result: PASSED
Test: checkForDbusName(powerd_cli_bus_name, 0, requests, TRUE)
    result: PASSED
```

Below is the full output and the syslog entries for a period where I
-start with a locked phone,
-turn on the screen by pressing the button
-wait for 2 minutes, and turn it off again. (lock time is 1 minute. Also doesn't turn off after 1hr)

```
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: handle_requestSysState from :1.13 (com.canonical.Unity.Screen) - ACTIVE (1)
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: name_watch_add: looking for :1.13
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: watching :1.13 to see when it disappears on dbus
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: acquire_wake_lock: powerd_power_request
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: handle_requestSysState - SUCCESS
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Enqueue state change to ACTIVE
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: exiting suspend
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: calling exit_suspend
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: exit_suspend succeeded
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Emitting signal for transition to state ACTIVE (1)
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Transition to ACTIVE complete
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: release_wake_lock: powerd_power_request
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: light_dev: setting brightness to 78
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: we get signal from :1.14: DisplayPowerStateChange
Jul  5 22:12:08 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Received DisplayPowerStateChange: state=1 flags=2
Jul  5 22:12:12 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: handle_requestSysState from :1.22 (usensord) - ACTIVE (1)
Jul  5 22:12:12 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: name_watch_add: looking for :1.22
Jul  5 22:12:12 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: watching :1.22 to see when it disappears on dbus
Jul  5 22:12:12 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: acquire_wake_lock: powerd_power_request
Jul  5 22:12:12 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: handle_requestSysState - SUCCESS
Jul  5 22:12:12 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Enqueue state change to ACTIVE
Jul  5 22:12:12 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: queue empty && state == current, discarding
Jul  5 22:12:12 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: release_wake_lock: powerd_power_request
Jul  5 22:12:15 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: handle_clearSysState from :1.22, cookie: 8096ad4e-6c90-4852-97e2-dac9866d21e0
Jul  5 22:12:15 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: clear_sys_request: usensord - :1.22
Jul  5 22:12:15 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: name_watch_remove: looking for :1.22
Jul  5 22:12:15 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: name_watch: ref_count for :1.22 is now 0
Jul  5 22:12:15 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: no longer watching :1.22, there are no more requests
Jul  5 22:12:15 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: acquire_wake_lock: powerd_power_request
Jul  5 22:12:15 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Enqueue state change to ACTIVE
Jul  5 22:12:15 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: queue empty && state == current, discarding
Jul  5 22:12:15 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: release_wake_lock: powerd_power_request
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: light_dev: setting brightness to 0
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: we get signal from :1.14: DisplayPowerStateChange
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Received DisplayPowerStateChange: state=0 flags=2
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: handle_clearSysState from :1.13, cookie: 28dfac1e-72a2-4e07-81c2-eb50380d620d
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: clear_sys_request: com.canonical.Unity.Screen - :1.13
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: name_watch_remove: looking for :1.13
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: name_watch: ref_count for :1.13 is now 0
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: no longer watching :1.13, there are no more requests
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: acquire_wake_lock: powerd_power_request
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Enqueue state change to SUSPEND
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: prepare_suspend.
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Emitting signal for transition to state SUSPEND (0)
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: entering suspend
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: calling enter_suspend
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: enter_suspend succeeded
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: Transition to SUSPEND complete
Jul  5 22:14:27 ubuntu-phablet powerd[3893]: libsuspend: release_wake_lock: powerd_power_request
```

What does it mean that `testdbus_name` is failing? What should happen when screen autolocks? Could someone else run some similar test and post log file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by factory resetting the phone: System Settings - Reset phone - Erase & Reset Everything.

This is not a very satisfying answer, as I had to reconfigure all sorts of stuff, but got the job done nonetheless.